# Loading an infinite table by incrementing page dynamically in htmx

Tags: infinite-scroll, htmx

I have a table setup using the Infinite Scroll example at htmx.org. The initial `hx-get` is set to something like `/new?limit=10&page=1`.

The `/new` handle populates the data and displays `page=1`, and the last row of the table has another `hx-get` as per the pattern with another `page=2`, but I have no idea how to increment this value other than on the server side as the user scrolls past the second `page` without resorting to cookies or data structures.

Can this be accomplished without complexity of maintaining state on the server side (which is golang in this case?

Comment: I think I may have found the solution, I just need to make sure...

Comment: Why do you need to maintain the state? Server receives current page number in the `page` query parameter, all it needs to do is to put `hx-get` to the last row with the `page+1` page.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I was confused. Thanks for the comment though. I can delete my question, but I think this might help others. If you'd like to use your comment in the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint `/new?limit=10&page=2` receives all the parameters for the next page, all you need to do is to form a URL for the next page using those parameters and increasing the page number.

So you don't need any state on the server side.